# Fixed Header hidden on JQuery Steps page (only on certain mobile browser)

Tags: html, css, jquery-steps

I can't seem to get my header to display on the page where the jquery-steps form are displayed. And this only happens on certain mobile browser such as the 360Browser(v1.1.0) and also the WeChat Built In browser.

I don't have any clue what might be wrong here so any help guys?

My test website is at [m.demo.rsi.sg](http://m.demo.rsi.sg). To get to the page, simply select any items (total checkout value must be > 40) and then proceed to checkout and click sign up.

Am nearly going bonkers over this - any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo"></div><div class="menu"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .header{position:fixed;
            top:0;
            z-index:2;
           }
</style>
```